# Escaped Input Data in Zend_Framework

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, sql-injection

Good day!

I want to protect my database when I save a row in the Zend_Framework:

```
function addController() {
....   
  if ($form->isValid($_POST)) {
   addRecods($form->getValues());
  }
}

class DbManager extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract
...
function addRecords(array $array) {
   $row = $this->createRow();
   $row->field1 = $this->field_from_form1;
   $row->field2 = $this->field_from_form2;
   ....
   $row->save(); 
}
```

How can I better escape input data from array in the `addRecords` function?

Thank you!

Comment: Is your form created via the Zend_Form component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Zend_Db_Table_Row::save()` function, internaly uses the `Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract::insert()` function to save data. Which in turn, quotes the data for you.

If you need to build your own sql queries, the the Zend_Db_Adapter classes provide several quoting functions for you to use. You can read more about them here: [Quoting Values and Identifiers](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.11/en/zend.db.adapter.html#zend.db.adapter.quoting)

Comment: Thank you! I have find this feature after you answer in class Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract:                                               public function insert($table, array $bind)
        {
            ....
            foreach ($bind as $col => $val) {
                $cols[] = $this->quoteIdentifier($col, true);

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, you are doing it the proper way. If your form is made using the `Zend_Form` you could add `filters` and `validators` on your form elements.

Every form elements I create automatically gets the `StripTags` (remove HTML tags) and `StringTrim` (remove unwanted whitespace) filters. The `StripTags` will need to be configured to accept specific tags and attributes if you need to allow HTML.

Over that, using validators will catch most of the malicious content. If you have radio buttons with numeric values, you can add the `Digit` validator. For strings the `Alnum` seems to give me weird results with accented (utf8) strings, but if you expect basic ASCII, it could be a runner up

Using the `Zend_Form::isValid()` will check if all the `validators` are OK and using `Zend_Form::getValues()` will automatically trigger all input `filters`. Since you are already doing this, you might just have to add proper `filters` and `validators`.

Using `Zend Framework`'s DB tools will do the rest of building a safe query for you to avoid quotes issues